# Is "Math Calculation" redundant when describing how to solve a problem?

Tags: word-usage, redundancy

I was corrected by another individual when describing the solution to a problem as a "math calculation". Is math implied when using calculation in a sentence therefore making my statement redundant?

Comment: You should have said a "mathematical calculation."

Comment: It would be rash to say that a word pair is ALWAYS redundant and therefore should ALWAYS be avoided. The "math calculation" duo is rare, and the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=math+calculation&year_start=1920&year_end=2000) shows it was non-existent for a long time, but there are instances (many of them in books talking about either word processors or measuring learning aptitude, so it may be jargon). I did find this in a book (and have no problem with it): _Modern calculators can do many calculations quickly. A complicated math calculation no longer is a big problem._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context. [*calculation*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/calculation) can mean

> careful planning or forethought, esp for selfish motives

or

> an estimation of probability; forecast

It isn't necessarily redundant, per se, but I'd say that you'd be hard-pressed to produce an example in which it wasn't redundant if the context of math is understood. If a math context wasn't previously understood, then it likely isn't redundant (there is possible ambiguity as to the aforementioned usages). In those situations, though, it's likely that qualifying with "mathematical" is just excessive or pedantic. I'd only use it if it's truly useful to.

Answer (score 1):

[To calculate is to determine a value mathematically](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/calculate), so I would say that "math calculation" is indeed redundant.

To be thorough, there are other definitions for *calculate* that take the general concept in a more colloquial direction: *his often-stated support for environmental protection always seemed very calculated.* In those cases, though, it's usually pretty obvious that you're not talking about mathematics, so it should rarely if ever be necessary to qualify a statement about mathematical calculation.